# Differentiate between 4.0.3 and 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there a way to differentiate between versions 4.0.3 and 4.0.4?

I've seen that `VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1` refers to both.

Comment: read version code and compare as String...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` to get the user-visible version String.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#RELEASE

> The user-visible version string. E.g., "1.0" or "3.4b5".

So, for example:

```
String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
Log.i(TAG, version);
if (version.equals("4.0.3")) {
    // do something
}
else if (version.equals("4.0.4")) {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some differences about android 4.0.4:

Noticeably Faster

Android OS bug fixed (in battery stats)

Long-pressing on a blank spot on the last page of app tray bug is gone

New Radios. 3G/4G switching MUCH better. Don't even notice it changing.

Improved signal strength

New Power Menu. New from 4.0.2, familiar to those who have used a stock 4.0.3 rom. Screenshot here

PRIMELA03 Bootloader

Faster boot up time

Auto-brightness Functionality changed. Smooth transition

Holding down camera button now refocuses again

Multitouch issue seems resolved. Screenshot here

Autorotate is faster

Browser performance noticeably improved

Recent apps list opens faster

Miscellaneous camera UI changes

Increased volume

Keyboard fixes

Updated News & Weather app UI

Improved quick controls in browser. New when coming from 4.0.2. Present in 4.0.3. Screenshot here (Update: 02/05)